# Page not found in opencart

Tags: php, url, opencart

I am working on opencart frontend and i have made sub-domain type of structure for every vendor. If vendor name is found in the url then it work as a different sub-domain

I want to redirect to page not found page if the vendor name entered is not present in the database. I am able to retrieve that information but i have no idea where to check that, weather in the index.php page or home.php or anywhere else.

My url is localhost/user/vendor_name.

Please help me to know from where can i redirect to not_found page.

Comment: The vendor feature is implemented by you? or did you some extension?

Comment: for admin i have used multivendor extension but for frontend i havent used any extension.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the frontend controller file of your vendor file added a condition like:

```
 if(vendor available){
 //Show the correct contents
  }else{

        $url = '';

        if (isset($this->request->get['path'])) {
            $url .= '&path=' . $this->request->get['path'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['filter'])) {
            $url .= '&filter=' . $this->request->get['filter'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['sort'])) {
            $url .= '&sort=' . $this->request->get['sort'];
        }   

        if (isset($this->request->get['order'])) {
            $url .= '&order=' . $this->request->get['order'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['page'])) {
            $url .= '&page=' . $this->request->get['page'];
        }

        if (isset($this->request->get['limit'])) {
            $url .= '&limit=' . $this->request->get['limit'];
        }

        $this->data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_error'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('vendor/vendor', $url),  //replace with vendor controllers
            'separator' => $this->language->get('text_separator')
        );

        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('text_error'));

        $this->data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

        $this->data['text_error'] = $this->language->get('text_error');

        $this->data['button_continue'] = $this->language->get('button_continue');

        $this->data['continue'] = $this->url->link('common/home');

        if (file_exists(DIR_TEMPLATE . $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl')) {
            $this->template = $this->config->get('config_template') . '/template/error/not_found.tpl';
        } else {
            $this->template = 'default/template/error/not_found.tpl';
        }

        $this->children = array(
            'common/column_left',
            'common/column_right',
            'common/content_top',
            'common/content_bottom',
            'common/footer',
            'common/header'
        );

        $this->response->setOutput($this->render());


}
```

Have a nice day !!

Comment: i am adding this condtion in home.php because that is the first page that is accessed. But it uses column_right,column_left and column_top and i have conditions for which data in those layouts are changed and thus giving large number of errors.
Any suggestions please.

Comment: I've no idea about your vendor files or the changes you've made in home. Also I strongly believe that the above code is not for the home controller. It needs to placed where you check the vendor exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code in the top of the `.htaccess` file to fix the 404 page not found error.

Prevent Directory listing

```
Options -Indexes
```

Prevent Direct Access to files

```
<FilesMatch “.(tpl|ini|log)”>
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
</FilesMatch>
```